# Find the expected number of people who select their own name tag

Tags: probability, statistics

At a party n people throw their name tags on a table. The name tags
are mixed up and then each people randomly and simultaneously selects one.
Find the expected number of people who select their own name tag.

Since the people choose simultaneously, I assumed that each has  $\frac{(n-1)!}{n!}$ or $\frac{1}{n}$ chance of selecting their own, thus expected number of people who get their own name tag is $ n\cdot \frac{1}{n} = 1 $. Am I correct in this?

Comment: *[Here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)* is some MathJax tutorial

Comment: I think that this question is essentially the famous *Hat Check Problem*, which has been asked here various times in several different versions (such as [this one](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/627913/131263) for example). If I'm not mistaken, then the answer is $\frac1e$ as $n$ tends to $\infty$.

Comment: @Daniel [link](https://duckduckgo.com/l/?kh=-1&uddg=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.cs.princeton.edu%2Fcourses%2Farchive%2Ffall06%2Fcos341%2Fhandouts%2Fvariance-notes.pdf) The answer looks like it is 1 by the linearity of expectation.

Comment: Ah, looking at the link you gave it is exactly the problem I was asking and by the comments the answer was indeed 1. Thanks!

Comment: @barakmanos It is indeed that problem, but here we are dealing with expectation (more easy). The probability that no person will get his own hat tends to $e^{-1}$ if $n$ tends to infinity.

Comment: @drhab: Thanks, I was indeed wondering whether it was the answer to the probability or to the expectation.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, you're right. To make the reasoning a little more precise, for each person $1,\dots,n$ we could define a Bernoulli random variable $X_i$, i.e., a random variable which takes one of only two possible values 0 and 1. We set $X_i$ to equal $1$ if the $i$th person draws their own name tag and $0$ if they do not. As you argue, the probability of any particular person drawing their own name tag is $1/n$. That is, $P(X_i=1)=1/n$. It follows that the expected value of $X_i$ is \begin{align*}
E(X_i)&=\sum_{x=0}^1 xP(X_i=x) \\
&= 0\cdot P(X_i=0)+1\cdot P(X_i=1) \\
&= 0+1/n \\
&= 1/n
\end{align*}
Now the total number of people who select their own name tag is $X_1+\cdots+X_n$, and we can use the linearity property of expected value to conclude that
$$E(X_1+\cdots+X_n) = E(X_1)+\cdots+E(X_n) = \frac1n+\cdots+\frac1n = n\cdot\frac1n = 1$$

Comment: Hmm.. what if the question had asked the number of pairs that exchanged tags?

Comment: @Huzo Please do not extend the posted problem in that way.  Instead, ask the question about (for example) the expected number of pairs of exchanged tags in a separate posted question.

Answer (score 1):

This is the expected number of fixed points in a random permutation which has combinatorial class in the notation from *Analytic Combinatorics*
$$\def\textsc#1{\dosc#1\csod}
\def\dosc#1#2\csod{{\rm #1{\small #2}}}\textsc{SET}(\mathcal{U}\times\textsc{CYC}_{=1}(\mathcal{Z}) 
+ \textsc{CYC}_{=2}(\mathcal{Z}) 
+ \textsc{CYC}_{=3}(\mathcal{Z}) 
+ \textsc{CYC}_{=4}(\mathcal{Z}) 
+\cdots).$$
This gives the generating function
$$G(z,u)
= \exp\left(uz +\frac{z^2}{2}+\frac{z^3}{3}+\frac{z^4}{4}+\cdots\right)$$
which is
$$G(z, u)
= \exp\left((u-1)z + z + \frac{z^2}{2}+\frac{z^3}{3}+\frac{z^4}{4}+\cdots\right)
= \frac{1}{1-z} \exp((u-1)z)
\\ = \frac{\exp(-z)}{1-z} \exp(uz).$$

To get the expected value compute
$$\left.\frac{\partial}{\partial u} G(z,u)\right|_{u=1}
= \left. \frac{\exp(-z)}{1-z} \exp(uz) \times z\right|_{u=1}
= \frac{z}{1-z}.$$

Extracting coefficients for the expected value we obtain
$$[z^n]\frac{z}{1-z} = 1$$
as claimed.